# Determine default menu in multilingual site

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have written a template for Joomla and I assign a class to `<body>` when current page is the front page or default menu. Code is like this:

```
<?php 
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$currentMenu = $app->getMenu();
$fp = ($currentMenu->getActive() == $currentMenu->getDefault()) ? ' frontpage' : '';
?>
...
<body class="<?php echo $fp; ?>">
    ...
```

and it was working until I tried to use it on a multilingual site. How can I determine if the current page is the default page of language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the language and language tag as shown below

```
<?php
  $app  = JFactory::getApplication();
  $lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
  $currentMenu = $app->getMenu();
  $fp = ($currentMenu->getActive() == $currentMenu->getDefault($lang->getTag())) ? ' frontpage' : '';
?>

<body class="<?php echo $fp; ?>">
```